# Algebras with a self-dual congruence lattice

Tags: category-theory, universal-algebra

The well known (Mal'tsev) conditions that characterize certain properties of the congruence lattice of an algebra. The existence of a 3-ary term $p$ together with familiar identities $p(x,y,y) \sim x \sim p(y,y,x)$, is equivalent to congruence permutability, for example. And imilar conditions exist for other lattice theoretic properties, such as distributivity and modularity.

Is there a term-condition, or an identity, that characterizes (or implies) varieties where every algebra has a self-dual congruence lattice?

A second question is if there is a Mal'tsev condition that implies that the every algebra has a complemented congruence lattice.

For example, the congruence lattice of a finite abelian group is self-dual. Or the congruence lattice of a finite dimensional vector space.

Comment: Directly related, but perhaps of not much help is the [paper by Taylor](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02945141) where he characterizes which properties of varieties are (strong, weak) Mal'cev conditions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question is about the following two properties of varieties:

1. The property that all members of $\mathcal V$
   have self-dual congruence
   lattices.
2. The property that all members of $\mathcal V$
   have complemented congruence
   lattices.

As Pedro observed, if all members have complemented congruence lattices,
then the subdirectly irreducible members must be simple [in a nonsimple
SI the monolith has no complement]. We can also say something about the SI's
under the assumption that all members have self-dual congruence lattices.

First note that if all members have self-dual congruence
lattices, then any *interval* in a congruence lattice is also self-dual. This follows from repeated use of self-duality
together with the fact that upper intervals are congruence lattices of
quotients.

Now assume that $\mathcal V$ has the property that its members have
self-dual congruence lattices. The bottom element of the congruence lattice
of an SI ${\mathbf S}$
is completely meet irreducible, so the top element must be completely join
irreducible. By the observation of the last paragraph, every nontrivial
upper interval is self dual. Since these intervals $[\sigma,1]$ have completely
join irreducible top element, they must also have completely
meet irreducible bottom element. Consequently every non-top
element in the congruence lattice of ${\mathbf S}$ is completely
meet irreducible, and similarly every non-bottom
element is completely join irreducible. The only algebraic lattices where
every non-top element is completely meet irreducible and every non-bottom
element is completely join irreducible are finite chains.

**Conclusion:** If every algebra in
${\mathcal V}$
has a self-dual congruence lattice, then the congruence lattice
of any SI in $\mathcal V$ is a finite chain.

Continuing to assume that members of $\mathcal V$ have self-dual congruence lattices, if ${\mathbf A}\in {\mathcal V}$ is nontrivial and $\alpha$
is a proper congruence on $\mathbf A$, then $\alpha$ can be enlarged
to $\beta$ so that ${\mathbf A}/\beta$ is SI. By the result of
the last paragraph, we may enlarge $\beta$ further to $\gamma$
if necessary where ${\mathbf A}/\gamma$ is simple. This shows that
every proper congruence $\alpha$ on a nontrivial algebra in $\mathcal V$
can be enlarged to a coatom $\gamma$. By self-duality we get that every nonzero congruence must lie above an atom.
This is a strong property to impose throughout a variety. It
is investigated in this paper:

[Atomicity and nilpotence, Canad. J. Math. 42(1990), 365-382.](http://cms.math.ca/10.4153/CJM-1990-020-1)

A result found there is that if every nonzero congruence on every
nontrivial algebra in $\mathcal V$ lies above an atom, then the ascending
central series for any ${\mathbf A}\in {\mathcal V}$ reaches the top congruence,
although perhaps after transfinitely many steps.

What it means here is that if we are in the case where $\mathcal V$ has
self-dual congruence lattices, then SI's in
$\mathcal V$ have congruence
lattices that are finite chains, and the SI algebras themselves are nilpotent.
(It is plausible that the SI's must even be abelian, 
but I see how to prove this only
for congruence modular varieties at the moment.)
If we are in the case where $\mathcal V$ has
complemented congruence lattices, then SI's in $\mathcal V$ are
simple and, as one can show by following the argument in the above paper, the SI's are abelian. In this case $\mathcal V$ is an abelian variety.

Now for the answers these questions:
*Is there is a Maltsev condition that implies that the
every algebra has a complemented congruence lattice?*
and
*Is there is a Maltsev condition that implies that the
every algebra has a self-dual congruence lattice?*

**Claim:** The only such Maltsev conditions are those
expressing that the variety is trivial.

This Claim rests on the following
*Observation:* If $\Sigma$ is a Maltsev condition
that is satisfied by a nontrivial variety, then it is satisfied
by a nontrivial discriminator variety. [If $\mathcal V$ satisfies
$\Sigma$, just add the discriminator $d$ to each member of $\mathcal V$
and generate a variety ${\mathcal V}^d$ with the resulting algebras.
${\mathcal V}^d$ is a discriminator variety satisfying any Maltsev
condition true in ${\mathcal V}$.]

To see how the Observation implies the Claim, assume
that $\Sigma$ is a Maltsev condition implying either that
congruence lattices are self-dual or implying that congruence
lattices are complemented. Let $\mathcal V$ satisfy $\Sigma$.
The discriminator variety ${\mathcal V}^d$ satisfies $\Sigma$, so
its SI's in ${\mathcal V}^d$
are nilpotent. But the only nilpotent members of a discriminator
variety are trivial, so ${\mathcal V}^d$ is trivial. $\mathcal V$
must also be trivial.

Comment: Very nice! I was missing your _Observation_ to round out my argument for complemented congruence lattice (many years working in varieties with poor structure). So, this observation implies that any non trivial Mal'cev condition must be consistent with arithmeticity, if I'm getting things straight.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer @Keith Kearnes, I appreciate it. (P.S please excuse the late reply)

Answer (score 5):

Some thoughts around the problem concerning complements.
$\newcommand{\calV}{\mathcal{V}}$

Let $\calV$ be a variety. The condition (call it **C**) that every algebra in $\calV$ has a complemented congruence lattice is rather strong. For instance, it implies *semisimplicity:* Every subdirectly irreducible algebra $A$ must be simple. This happens since every such $A$ has a least nonzero congruence, which must be the greatest one in order to have a complement.

But more interestingly, this property is “incompatible” with congruence-distributivity; this means that the only congruence-distributive variety satisfying **C** is the trivial one. One proof of this fact goes along the following lines.

Assume $\calV$ is a congruence-distributive variety satisfying **C**. Let $A$ be a simple member of $\calV$, and $B$ the Boolean algebra of finite and cofinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. You can construct the *Boolean power* (check the online book [A Course in Universal Algebra](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~snburris/htdocs/ualg.html) for this) $P=A[B]^*$, and in the case at hand the lattice of congruences of $P$ is isomorphic to that of $B$ (see, for instance, A. G. Pinus, [Boolean Constructions in Universal Algebras](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780792321170), Lemma 3.2 and Corollary 3.1). But it is easy to see that the lattice of congruences of $B$ is not complemented; actually, the congruence associated to the cofinite filter has no complement.

On the other hand, if you have a congruence-permutable variety satisfying **C**, every congruence of any of its members must be a factor congruence. This is also rather suspicious.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer @Pedro Sanchez Terraf! - (please excuse how late this reply is)

Comment: @MichaelHoefnagel You're welcome.